# How Can I Multiply Two Arrays Like int[] * int[] in Java?

Tags: java

I want to multiply two arrays in java. Is there any function for that or how can I do that?

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] b = new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] c = a * b; ?
```

I researched a bit but could not find.

Comment: `int[] c = IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(i -> a[i] * b[i]).toArray();`

Comment: Well, this is quite easy to so even without streams and lambdas. Just create target array of sufficient length, loop over the indices of the input arrays, multiply the elements at the source indices and assign them to the corresponding target index. So what the stream is doing is essentially this: `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { c[i] = a[i] * b[i]; }`. If `a` and `b` have different lengths things get a little more complex but not by much.

Comment: Do you just want c[x] = a[x] * b[x] or something more complicated?  If it is something more complicated, you have to tell us what you really want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built in functionality for this. However, it can be done manually, using streams, libraries, or a number of other approaches.

The easiest and most straightforward approach is to use a for loop.

```java
static int[] arrayMultiply(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int newLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    int[] c = new int[newLength];

    for (int index = 0; index < newLength; index++) {
        c[index] = a[index] * b[index];
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Although... we may be able to exploit the hotspot intrinsic for `java/math/BigInteger.multiplyToLen([II[II[I)[I` using reflection to get marginally better performance for extremely massive arrays. So in a way I guess there is a built-in way for array multiplication. However it would almost certainly be better to just write a JNI function for it at that point.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics matrix multiplication, the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix. Then the row elements of first matrix multiply by column elements in second matrix to get resulting matrix. Although this is much different, can get results of this is one-dimensional array like this.

[1 2 3] * [1 2 3] = [1x1  1x2  1x3] = [1 2 3]

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {1,2,3};
int c[] = new int[a.length]; 
    
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){   
    c[i] = a[0]*b[i]; 
    System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
}
```

If you are going to have mathematical matrix multiplications, this will be the correct way.